# Woocommerce Collapsible Checkout Form

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, accordion

I am having troubles making a WooCommerce collapsible checkout form work properly. I am using Bootstrap Collapse for this, and here's my HTML markup:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="checkout-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel-billing">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-billing">Delivery Address</a> </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-billing" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-1">
                <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_checkout_billing');
?>
           </div>

            <div class="col-2">
                <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_checkout_shipping');
?>
           </div>
        </div>
        <button id="next1" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-delivery"> Next </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel-shipping">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-delivery">Delivery Options</a> </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-delivery" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <?php
if (WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping()):
?>

            <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping');
?>

            <?php
    wc_cart_totals_shipping_html();
?>

            <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping');
?>

        <?php
endif;
?>
        <button id="next2" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-payment"> Next </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to have an accordion with different sections. The first section will be visible by default, but the others won't be toggleable by default. They will appear as greyed out, as if they were not editable/selectable. Once the first section of the form is filled out, there will be a "Next" button that will toggle the next section of the accordion (which is hidden by default). And so on.

However, once the next section is toggled, the previous one should collapse, which isn't happening. I want just one panel opened at a time. What am I doing wrong? I checked and I'm quite sure the markup is right, so I'd really appreciate a bit of input/suggestions.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hdpgp9sf/ (interestingly, the snippet is working properly here, but not on my site).

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Are jquery and bootstrap.js included in your project?

Comment: And do you have any console errors? Do you have a live link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the "bootstrap.js" file. I replaced

```
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
// For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

with

```
 function xobamax_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xobamax_resources');
```

in my functions.php and is working now. However, when the panels collapse, the content inside `<div class="panel body"></div>` overflows the parent, `<div class="panel-collapse collapse"></div>`, plus the collapsing action is not very "smooth". It is jumpy/bouncy. I had to add an extra `details` class to the `panel-collapse collapse` div with the following styling to make it work:

```
.details {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

I hope it helps anyone with a similar problem!